# Why is my data getting inserted twice? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I just can't figure this out. I have a CSV with 174638 rows. Here is a sample:

```
015826136@domain.com,2010-11-08 14:10:35
01DETAIL@domain.com,2011-11-01 20:14:21
01krisp10@domain.com,2010-11-08 15:00:09
01luis@domain.com,2010-11-08 15:00:09
01tthomas@domain.com,2010-11-08 15:09:13
02570734@domain.com,2011-10-10 11:44:54
02arman02@domain.com,2010-11-08 14:53:26
03091980@domain.com,2010-11-08 14:45:09
03331025@domain.com.com,2010-11-08 14:45:09
```

I don't need or use the 2nd column (date), only the first (email).

I am reading the CSV and looping through the rows, and inserting the email addresses into a database table. When I run another file where I've save 4000 of these same records, it runs fine. When I run the full one, each row gets inserted twice. All of them, then all of them again. Of course the php page times out as well. If I comment out the insert and echo each email, they are only echo'd one time to the screen.

Here is the PHP code:

```
if ( isset($_POST["step"]) && $_POST["step"] == '2' ) {

    if ( isset($_FILES["file"])) {

            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0) {
                $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name'])));
                $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
                $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

                // check the file is a csv
                if($ext === 'csv'){
                    if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {

                        $field = $_POST['field'];
                        //clear the import table
                        mysql_query("TRUNCATE table iContact_import");

                        //loop through the CSV
                        while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 300, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                            //$info = explode(",", $line);
                            //echo $info[0].'<br/>';
                            mysql_query("INSERT iContact_import (email,field) values ('".$data[0]."','".$field."')");                                   
                        }

                        echo '<h3 style="color:green;">Database is prepped for new subscribers</h3>';
                        echo '<p><a href="icontact_process.php?step=3">Click here to update subscriptions</a></p>';

                    }

                } else {
                    echo '<p>File is not a CSV. Please use another field with CSV values and extension.</p>';
                }

            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
            }

    } else {
        echo '<p>Please upload a CSV file with email addresses to import.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Put an `exit` right statement after the `while(fgetscsv)` loop. If you still get duplicate rows your entire script must be getting called _twice_

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: Ya that's what I am getting hung up on, he states in his post he runs it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing dupe rows because you are not tracking what has already been entered into the database. If you want to ensure this doesn't happen you can add a unique key to the email column of the database, this will ensure only unique email addresses are added.

However  you will have to add some sort of error handling otherwise your script will halt when it attempts to insert a dupe.

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` ADD UNIQUE KEY (`email`);
```

Comment: I went ahead and did this, which helped somewhat. I made this change and then ran the script. I watched the full amount of records get loaded in and then the table record count went back to 0 and it began inserting them all again. Since a line in the code above clears the table, I removed it and ran it again. This time it inserted all the records once, but the page timed out at the same time phpMyAdmin showed the last records being inserted. I would expect my success message to show at this point...

Comment: ...however, I still think there is some kind of loop that I can't see, since I had these scenarios:

1. email not unique and no truncate table line: all records entered more than once until script times out.
2. email unique and truncate table line: all records entered once, table cleared, all records entered again until script times out.
3. email unique and no truncate table line: all records entered once, script times out.

Comment: @user604844: What do you mean the page timed out? Did you get a memory exhausted message? or your browser just gave up? Typically, scripts such as the one you are running are usually run from the command line, so the browser doesn't get involved.

Comment: The browser gave up. This is a web page that a client of mine will run to import subscriptions from iContact so that we can show certain info to site users who are subscribed to specific lists in iContact. This will be run from a website every time. My original post talks about a PHP script and shows PHP code. Clearly I'm not using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> However you will have to add some sort of error handling otherwise
>   your script will halt when it attempts to insert a dupe.

If you're using MySQL5 you can use INSERT IGNORE for that

Answer (score 0):

You also may want to use a [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) with an IGNORE option. It will help you to load data from the CSV file using one MySQL command and ignore duplicates; you only should make `email` field UNIQUE (like Digital Precision suggested).

Another way is to load data into the second (or temporary table), then copy data to first table using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it runs twice because http connection and output buffer issue. If your request running too long (longer than 10 min.) to finish, than your browser sends the same request to your server. Modern browsers act like that. So i guess this is your problem...

Try to put those on top of your codes;

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Connection: close\r\n");
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
ignore_user_abort(true); // optional
ob_start();
echo ('Process running...');
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
ob_end_flush();     // Strange behaviour, will not work
flush();            // Unless both are called !
ob_end_clean();

//PUT YOUR CODES HERE
```

this codes close the http connection after requesting. So your code safely runs only once.